# Issues with Android in-app Billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am trying to run the sample in-app billing as supplied on the developers site.

I had things working at one point, where I was able to buy a potion, and things would show up in the sample app as purchased.

At some point, things stopped working with only minor modifications, so I reverted back to the original sample code and things still aren't working. At first the purchase page would say my item was not available, even though I could see the product description behind the dialog. Soon after, the store couldn't find the items at all. None of my versions of the sample app will display the items that I own anymore, including the test items.

All I get is this in LogCat:

> E/Volley  ( 1619): [12] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected
>   response code 500 for
>   https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=inapp:com.bdfun.dungeons:potion_001

and

> D/Finsky  ( 1619): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode:
>   Sending response RESULT_ERROR for request  to
>   com.bdfun.dungeons.

I'm totally at a loss as to why this has completely stopped working, and I'm finding it impossible to debug it.

Appreciate any tips that anyone can provide.

Comment: I'm not sure if my issue is because I have been interacting with the play stores too much, because the app can see my store items again after having a short break.

Comment: There is some automatic rate limiting, so it is possible that you got temporarily blocked. Same things happens if you issue RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS too often.